# Using an html file to alter a php script

Tags: javascript, php, html, json, forms

I have a very small php script used by an iPhone app that returns two time stamps:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $starttime = "2014-04-28 19:31:00 -0400";
    date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); 
    $servertime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s O', time());
    echo '{"servertime":"'.$servertime.'","starttime":"'.$starttime.'"}';
?>
```

I want to have a simple html page that can grab and display the contents of $starttime and change it.  My html skills are very, very rusty; and I'm pretty new to php.  I have an html page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h1>Control start time</h1>
<p>Current time: <iframe src="http://free.timeanddate.com/clock/i44omrtl/n2428/tt0/tw0/tm3/td2/th1/tb2" frameborder="0" width="131" height="18"></iframe></p>    
<form name="htmlform" method="post" action="changetime.php">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td valign="top">
                <label for="movie_time">Start time: </label>
            </td>
            <td valign="top">
                <input type="text" name="month" maxlength="2" size="5">/
                <input type="text" name="day" maxlength="2" size="5">/
                <input type="text" name="year" maxlength="4" size="8">&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <input type="text" name="hour" maxlength="2" size="5">:
                <input type="text" name="minutes" maxlength="2" size="5">:
                <input type="text" name="seconds" maxlength="2" size="5">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>    
</body>
</html>
```

I'm a little lost now on how to proceed.  What's the next step?  Or have I missed a much better implementation given my lack of recent experience?

Comment: When you say `change it`, are you saying just for the client side? if so, you can use `ajax` to directly communicate with the server and in the `success` response you can alter the time stamp that is returned.

Comment: You should never have to change a php file programatically. If a value needs a different setting, use a config file or something similar and have both php scripts use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the starttime into an external file (for example starttime.txt) and then use it like this:

```
<?php
    header('Content-type: application/json');
    $starttime = file_get_contents("starttime.txt"); //"2014-04-28 19:31:00 -0400";
    date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); 
    $servertime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s O', time());
    echo '{"servertime":"'.$servertime.'","starttime":"'.$starttime.'"}';
?>
```

You can then create another script to get and change the starttime:

```
<?php

    if($_POST[starttime] != "")
        if(file_put_contents("starttime.txt", $_POST[starttime]) !== false)
            echo "ERFOLGREICH GESICHERT\n\n<br /><br />";

    $starttime = file_get_contents("starttime.txt");

    echo "<form action='' method='post'>Starttime: <input type='text' name='starttime' value='". $starttime ."' /><input type='submit' value='Sichern'></form>";

?>
```

Take care that the starttime.txt file is writeable for everyone(chmod 0777), so that the script can save the new value.

Comment: Thank you for this.  This, and the other comments, pointed me in the right direction.